# Using e Fx and w in grep in loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep

I have a file with IDS

```
cat id.csv
154,art
155,art.br
```

and another with with TLDs

```
cat tld.csv
art
abc
```

when I run with loop like

```
while read -r tld
do

cat id.csv | grep -w "$tld" >> final.csv

done < tld.csv
```

it catch the `art.br` as well

I tried

```
grep -E "^$tld$"
```

and

```
grep -Fx $tld
```

both give blank result

I only want `art` to be out as result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cat id.csv | grep -E ",$tld$" >> final.csv

Answer (score 0):

`-w` option specifies a whole word. `art` is a whole word in both `154,art`
and `155,art.br` strings.

You may add a `$` in grep search string (`grep -w "$tld$" id.csv`), but I am unsure it will be enough (it would match `150,foo.art` for example).

The best would be to simply match the full word after the last comma (the `-w` option becomes useless):

```
grep ",${tld}$" id.csv
```

Or, to catch also lines with some trailing spaces :

```
grep ",${tld}[[:blank:]]*$" id.csv
```

**Note:** You should always avoid the useless `cat file | command`, and either prefer `command < file` or `command file`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
tlds=$(<tld.csv)
grep -E ",(${tlds//$'\n'/'|'})\$" id.csv
```

assuming `tld.csv` doesn't contain a regexp metacharacter.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is that lines in `tld.csv` must exactly match (the entirety of) the second column of lines in `id.csv`, then an `awk` solution is quite efficient:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{tld[$1];next} $2 in tld' tld.csv id.csv
154,art
```

- `-F,` - delimit input fields by comma (records are delimited by newline)
- `NR==FNR` - while reading first file:

  - `tld[$1]` - remember column 1 value (add as array index)
  - `next` - skip remaining commands; read next line
- `$2 in tld` - if 2nd column (of second file) is an index of `tld` (ie. exactly matches a value stored from the first file), then perform default action (ie. print line)

This assumes that lines in `tld.csv` cannot contain commas and that any whitespace (in either file) is significant.